# Installing application after download: `There is a p‌r‌o‌b‌l‌e‌m parsing the package`

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, sign

I am trying to **download an install** a .apk file from an application. Here are 3 different situations:

**1.** From Eclipse to Tablet via adb **>** Run application **>** No problems
**2.** From Eclipse **>** Sign & Export **>** Transfer .apk file to tablet via USB **>** Install & Run application **>** No problems
**3.** From Eclipse **>** Sign & Export **>** (The same file from 2.) Upload .apk file to a server **>** Download .apk file from application **>** Try to install **>** "There is a problem parsing the package"

**code for downloading the application:**

```
private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            // this will be useful so that you can show a typical 0-100% progress bar
            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

            // download the file
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Download" + File.separator + "Design102.apk");

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Why am I getting "There is a problem parsing the package" error for the same .apk file after downloading?

Comment: What happens if you uninstall the app and then re-install it from market?

Comment: It's not on the market.

Comment: OK. Is it already installed while you trying to install it after download is finished?

Comment: Yes, and I get the error "There is a problem parsing the package". However, if I transfer the same .apk file via USB instead of downloading it, I can install it.

Comment: Do a bit-wise diff between the original file and the downloaded one. I have a feeling they won't be the same

Comment: Downloaded file is different.

Comment: so the problem is in your downloading code.

Comment: Tunnel vision sucks. Focused on the download code after your comment, and it seems the problem was: while ((count = input.read(data)) > 0)

Comment: Write it down as answer if you like, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following minor modification fixed my problem:

```
       while ((count = input.read(data)) > 0)
```